# res.json Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: json, node.js, session, express

I'm learning node Js and i'm trying to do a simple subscribe/log_in app.
I'm having issue with res.json not working as intended.

Got this error when i'm trying to subscribe : **Can't set headers after they are sent**

This is my server side script :

```
var express = require('express');
var swig = require('swig');
var ent = require('ent');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session');

var app = express();

// Environnement
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view cache', false);
swig.setDefaults({ cache: false });
app.use(session({
    secret: 'poussixthetruefighteroftheparadise',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

//MongoDB
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/maBase');
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    login:  String,
    mail: String,
    password: String
});
var user = db.model('user', userSchema)

// variables globales
var state;




// Page Principale
app.get('/', function(req,res){

    if (req.session.user) {
        res.render('accueil.html',{});
    } else {
        res.redirect('/connection');
    }

});

// Page connection
app.route('/connection')
    .get(function(req, res) {

        res.render('index.html',{});

        if (req.session.state) {
            res.json({state: req.session.state});
        }

    })
    .post(function(req, res) {

        user.find({login: req.body.login, password: req.body.password}).limit(1).exec(function (err, users) {

            if (err) { console.log(err) };

            if (!users.length) {

                console.log('connection pas ok');

                res.json({state: '5'});

            }
            else {

                console.log('connection ok');
                res.redirect('/');

            }

        });

    });


// Ajouter Utilisateur
app.post('/connection/ajouter', function(req,res){

    var login = req.body.login;
    var mail = req.body.mail;

    user.find({$or: [{login: login}, {mail: mail}]}).limit(1).exec(function (err, users) {

        if (err) { console.log(err) };

        if (!users.length) {

            console.log('login et mail ok');

            if (req.body.password == req.body.password2) {

                if (req.body.password.length > 6) {

                    var values = new user({
                            login: ent.encode(req.body.login),
                            mail: ent.encode(req.body.mail),
                            password: ent.encode(req.body.password)
                    });

                    values.save(function(err, values) {

                        if (err) return console.error(err);

                        console.log('utilisateur enregistré');

                        req.session.state = '6';
                        res.redirect('/connection');

                    });

                } else {

                    console.log('Mot de passe trop court');

                    req.session.state = '3';
                    res.redirect('/connection');

                }


            } else {

                console.log('mot de passe différent');

                req.session.state = '4';
                res.redirect('/connection');

            }

        }

        else {

            console.log('login ou mail déja utilisé');

            if (users[0].mail == mail) {

                console.log('mail déja utilisé');
                req.session.state = '2';
                res.redirect('/connection');

            } else {

                console.log('login déja utilisé');
                req.session.state = '1';
                res.redirect('/connection');

            }

            console.log(users);

        }

    });

});




app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

And my client side script :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/connection.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="content">

        <a href="http://localhost:3000"><img src="public/images/icone.jpg" alt="gatsbill"></a>

        <div id="wrap">

            <div id="espacehaut"></div>
            <div class="click" id="con" style="display: block;">Se connecter</div>
            <div class="click" id="sub" style="display: none;">S'inscrire</div>

            <div id="connection" style="display: none;">
                <div id="message1" class="message" style="display: none;"></div>
                <form action="/connection/" method="post" id="form_connection">
                    <input type="text" name="login" id="login" placeholder="Login" value="" required="" autofocus="">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Connect">
                </form>
            </div>

            <div id="subscribe" style="">
                <p id="p">Pour vous inscrire,<br> Veuillez remplir les champs ci-dessous</p>
                <div id="message2" class="message" style="display: none;"></div>
                <form action="/connection/ajouter/" method="post" id="form_inscription">
                    <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Login" value="" required="" autofocus="">
                    <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Email" value="" required="">
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
                    <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Password" required="">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create account">
                </form>
            </div>

            <div id="espacebas"></div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Script -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/connection.js"></script>
    <script>

        $.getJSON( "http://localhost:3000/connection", function(data){
            if( data.state ) {
                state = parseInt(data.state);
                switch (state) {
                    case 1:
                        formulaire();
                        $("#message2").text("login déja utilisé");
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        formulaire();
                        $("#message2").text("mail déja utilisé");
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        formulaire();
                        $("#message2").text("Mot de passe trop court");
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        formulaire();
                        $("#message2").text("mot de passe différent");
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        connect();
                        $("#message1").text("connection pas ok");
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        connect();
                        $("#message1").text("vous pouvez maintenant vous connecter");
                        break;

                }
            }
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

When i'm trying to subscribe with two different password this is what I have :

A white page with only this :

{"state":"4"}

And of course this error in node Js console: **Can't set headers after they are sent**

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Welcome to nodejs/express!

This is where you are getting your "Can't set headers after they are sent" error in the console:

```
// Page connection
app.route('/connection')
    .get(function(req, res) {

        res.render('index.html',{});

        if (req.session.state) {
            res.json({state: req.session.state});
        }

    })
```

In this configuration, `res.render` and `res.json` will both call `res.end()` which is basically like trying to send a response twice to the client.

You should place a `return` statement before `res.render` or set `{state: req.session.state}` as the second param to your `res.render()` call and then use a swig template to display that data.

Comment: thx for this fast answer, I understand why it can't work the way I did

Comment: This was hard to debug. `return res.send()` worked but `res.send(); return;` didn't fix it.

Comment: @AlexW Thats because `res.send()` executes asynchronously and therefore the latter will execute `res.send()` and `return` in parallel where as the formal will return the immediately return after calling of `res.send()` and therefore halt further execution of the parent function.

Comment: Yep I get why it worked. I just posted that in case that subtle nuance is misunderstood by future readers of the answer. I.e., the wording was confusing to me at first.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it this way:

Override res.send in the very first middleware:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    var _send = res.send;
    var sent = false;
    res.send = function(data){
        if(sent) return;
        _send.bind(res)(data);
        sent = true;
    };
    next();
});
```

Comment: WAT? why would you do that?

Comment: I ended up doing something similar because of a bug in a plugin which causes a callback to be called twice.  Don't want to fork the plugin and can't wait for the bug to be fixed so I did this as a holdover : 
if (!sent){ 
 response.sendStatus(203).end; 
 sent = true;
}